# Fastest conversion of 3d list to numpy array (cython?)

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a problem since I found out that converting a large list to an array is very slow I looked for faster ways. I stumpled over cython. The only thing I found for conversion is the standard wy with np.array(a,dtype=np.float32)

I would like to cast a 3d list like the following into an array with cython?

```
a = [[[1,2,3,8],[4,1,2,4],[1,2,3,8],[4,1,2,4], [4,1,2,4]],[[3,5,3,8],[4,3,2,5],[1,2,3,8],[4,1,2,4], [4,1,2,4]]]
```

How could I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: What are the typical dimensions of the 3D array? Is the list data int (as in your example) or float?

Comment: You can use the inner dims as like above, but they are fixed. float is preferable

Comment: So, shape `(n, 5, 4)` with some large `n`? Is it no option to not create this data as numpy array or maybe a list of `(1000, 5, 4)`-shaped arrays that can be concatenated (with a counter to keep track of `n`)? I don't expect a speedup with Cython compared to the compiled numpy code. Handling Python lists is just slow.

Comment: `np.array` already is compiled code.  It has a lot to.  From the nesting it has to determine the shape.  It has to check each terminal element for type, and convert to the common or desired `dtype`.  The underlying data structure for an array is totally different from your list.

Comment: Yes I thought so, but how would I create such an array with manual numbers by my hand? I manaul createdd this lists by nested for loops trhough othger lists to set each number at its specific dimension. Can I do nested for loops within np.arrays?